# Update a spreadsheet by sheet name

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I need to use google-doc-api to update my site details. In the google developer forum and documentation they only specify to update a sheet value using feed entries id

eg : `WorksheetEntry worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)wsFeed.Entries[0];`

In above code, we can edit the first sheet. But my case is different. I have only sheet name like Sheet1, Sheet2 ..etc. So how I find sheet and add my values to the sheet that I specify.

Answer (score 0):

To get sheet names:

```
  foreach (WorksheetEntry entry in wsFeed.Entries)
  {
    // Get the worksheet's title, row count, and column count.
    string title = entry.Title.Text;
    int rowCount = entry.Rows;
    int colCount = entry.Cols;

    // Print the fetched information to the screen for this worksheet.
    Console.WriteLine(title + "- rows:" + rowCount + " cols: " + colCount);
  }
```

from:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets